# Why does changing the CPU frequency make the monitor display an error message?

Tags: memory, cpu, overclocking, fsb

Using MSI ClickBIOS2, I tried to overclock, but noticed an odd problem:
Changing the *base frequency* allows me to overclock the RAM and such all at once, but although the system boots any amount of change to that number causes the monitor to say "input out of range". The odd thing, is that behind that message the desktop does in fact show, though it's a bit fuzzy. What causes this to occur?

Comment: Just a guess... your gfx card doesn't have it's own clock generator. Are you using the built-into-the-chipset gfx, perhaps?

Comment: Have you got control once the desktop loads? Or is it frozen?

Comment: desktop works perfectly, that's the odd part. I would have assumed if the monitor is not getting the pattern, it wouldn't display. but yet it does. and yes, it's a Radeon inside an APU- it that the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The APUs should be able to be overclocked. I would contact AMD. But you void warranty when overclocking anything – just FYI.

I don't overclock. I have not needed to since I went from an Athlon XP to Athlon 64 and still to this day see no point in overclocking for no visual improvements. Voiding lifetime warranty on my CPU is not worth the minor performance increase.

You want speed get an OCZ Agility 3 240GB SSD. They read/write at an amazing 500MB/s and they are less then a buck a gig where I am from. Just make sure to install Windows in AHCI mode in the BIOS. And install the AHCI drivers from the motherboard's website so the SSD can use its TRIM command properly.

Don't overclock RAM either – just get the correct timings from the manufacturer's website or use the motherboard's built-in memory profile. I only had one profile and it put the voltages up to the proper 1.65 from 1.5. That immediately took it from 1333 to the proper 1600 MHz with the proper timings 9-9-9. I have an AMD Phenom II 955Black Ed CPU and an AMD A8 5600k APU.

Comment: the multiplier works fine, I can set it to 40 and the APU will run at 4GHz. it's just the base that doesn't.

Comment: slhck.... Thanks but no thanks I was on a mobile device it's hard enough to touchtype as it is then to use proper punctuation and my shift key... esp when replying while taking a relaxing bath.

Comment: ZCoder - My answer was trying to steer you away from Overclocking as it's a waste of hardware and not needed especially with the improvements made to hardware in the last decade. You Void Warranty for no noticeable improvements and potential lose of hardware if OC goes wrong. Your speed will be dramatically increased with the addition of an SSD or even a Hybrid HDD(SSHD), also instead of overclocking just set your RAM Timing and Voltage to the correct specifications and that way your RAM is fine tuned to proper Specifications, I use Kingston HyperX Red and it's timings are 9-9-9-9 and 1.65V